Turn off shadows and reflections
How to turn off white shadows/reflectins on an objects like in the attached image?

I'd like the blender to display simplest, purest view possible to fit some textures on meshes. I absolutely don't need any lights, shadows, reflections etc. Just an uniform sun like light to evenly light up the scene.

Maybe you want https://blender.stackexchange.com/ ? stackoverflow is for programming Q&A.
